# CSS Gradient Border with Rounded Corners has Unexpected Gap Between Background and Border

Tags: css, button, gradient

I am looking to create a button with a gradient border that fades-in and out on hover:

Codepen [here](https://codepen.io/mr-sudo/pen/mdGKBEN):

```
background: linear-gradient(rgb(25, 25, 25), rgb(25, 25, 25)) padding-box, linear-gradient(160deg, #2787FF, #54D1A4) border-box;
```

[image: An animation of the goal button design]

However, using the border-box and padding-box on the background of the element causes an unexpected space on the corners of the button, causing the gradient border to peer through before hovering.

[image]

Is it possible get rid of this small space while keeping the existing animation style of the gradient border fading in and out?

Answer (score 1):

@mr.sudo -

You can remove padding-box. This should fix it.

```
 .btn{
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight:500;
  padding : 20px 10px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  color: white;
  background: linear-gradient(rgb(25, 25, 25), rgb(25, 25, 25)), linear-gradient(160deg, #2787FF, #54D1A4) border-box;
  border: 10px solid rgb(25, 25, 25);
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.btn:hover{
  background: linear-gradient(rgb(25, 25, 25), rgb(25, 25, 25)) padding-box, linear-gradient(160deg, #2787FF, #54D1A4) border-box;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
}
```

Comment: this does remove the white space, but now the gradient border doesn't appear when hovering over the button at all :(

Comment: @mr.sudo I actually made a mistake in my last code, I revised the above. You must keep padding-box on the :hover state.

Comment: @mr.sudo Here is a Pen I made with the edit https://codepen.io/rutledgeismyname/pen/OJowMJZ

Comment: thank you as this is much closer, although now when un-hovering the style snaps back to the gray border instead of fading back